# Print prime number satisfying following equation

Tags: python, primes, equation

I want to find prime number satisfy the following equation. Equation is : pn = 2^k +1 , k <= 32

I can't get any output. Where am I doing wrong? Can you show it on the code?

```
def  is_prime(x):
for k in range(1, 32 + 1):
    if k > 1:
        for i in range (2 , k):
            if (k % i) == 0:
                break
            else:
                p = 2**k+1
                if is_prime (p):
                    print (p)
```

Comment: `for k in range(1, 33):` `p = 2**k+1` `if is_prime(p):` `print(p)` (for body of `def is_prime(x)` please refer to THE WEB...)

Comment: Can you show on the code ? I don't understand this way. Thank you

Comment: I can't make sense of the `(k%i)==0` test.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what I wanted ta say was:
Instead of iterating over every single number from 1 to 2^32, rather iterate over the 32 exponents of your numbers of interest only and check them against being prime or not.

E.g.

```
from math import sqrt
def is_prime(x):
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(x))+1):
        if x%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

for k in range(1, 33):
    p = 2**k+1
    if is_prime(p):
        print(f'{k:2}: {p}')

#  1: 3
#  2: 5
#  4: 17
#  8: 257
# 16: 65537
```